# Express the vector field in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

$\underline{G}=(8r^7x-5r^3y)\underline{i}+(-8r^7y+5r^3x)\underline{j}$

where $r=(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

How would I express the vector field as cylindrical coordinates? I have looked at various examples but none of them translate to an example such as this, any help would be fantastic!

Comment: typo ??$\underline{G}=(8r^7x-5r^3y)\underline{i}+(-8r^7y+5r^3x)\underline{j}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you will want to use the substitutions $x =r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$ for the polar angle $\theta$.  The next part is in changing the unit vectors from $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ to $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$.  Verify for yourself that $\hat{r} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( \hat{i} + \hat{j})$.  We will want $\hat{\theta}$ to be orthogonal to $\hat{r}$ (think of this as pointing in the direction of increasing $\theta$) so this can be taken to be $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( \hat{i} - \hat{j})$.  You can solve the equations for $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ in terms of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ and substitute the values for $x$ and $y$ as well.

Comment: I have this, I am not sure if I have completed the conversion as I havent done anything with r, but wanted to show where I am at.

Comment: $\underline{G}=8r^8(cos^2{\theta}-sin^2{\theta})\underline{e}_{r}+(-16r^{8}cos{\theta}sin{\theta} +5r^4)\underline{e}_{\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

After changing to polar coordinates by sustitution

$$ x= r \cos \theta ;\; y= r \sin \theta $$

take out $r^4 $ common. After this, switching back to cylindrical coordinates makes it easier.